# How to assign a new value with a subscribe within another subscribe?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

so I have these campaigns that I want to fetch and then change the `exepected_eta` value for each of those campaigns, I do that now with the following

```
  fetchCampaign() {
    if (this.producer?.active_campaign) {
      this.campaignService.getCampaignByNumber(this.producer!.active_campaign).subscribe((campaign) => {
        this.campaign = campaign
        this.campaign.expected_eta = this.expectedEta(this.campaign.campaign_number)
      })
    }
  }
```

and this is how the expectedEta() looks like

```
  expectedEta(campaign_number: number) {
    let eta: any
    this.campaignService.getExpectedEta(campaign_number).subscribe(campaign => {eta = campaign.eta;}); 
        return eta;
  }
```

Now this results in a subscribe within a subscribe and the expectedEta can't return the value as it is doing now. I know somehow a `pipe` and `forkJoin` could fix this but i'm not entirely sure how to set it up.
Can any of you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `forkJoin` would not work here since the second call depends on the first one. But you can use a `switchMap` instead.

```
fetchCampaign() {
  this.campaignService.getCampaignByNumber(this.producer!.active_campaign).pipe(
    switchMap(campaign => {
      this.campaign = campaign
      return this.campaignService.getExpectedEta(campaign.number)
    })
  ).subscribe(eta => {
    this.campaign.expected_eta = eta
  })
}
```